# Listing files from a remote directory with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file, controller, remote-server

I have a samba server on our network which contains a number of directories, one of the directories is full of .xls Microsoft Excel documents.

What I am trying to achieve is basically a list of the files within the remote directory which I can then mash up into a link which includes the remote IP. The end result is basically a live table of the files in the directory which the user can click on to open the file they need.

I've read about the following method of doing something similar:

```
basedir = '.'
files = Dir.glob("*.xls")
```

What I am trying to work out, is how do I make the basedir a remote IP and also how I would build this into my model/controller.

Ideally I would like to do something like this:

**file_controller.rb**

```
class FilesController < ApplicationController

 basedir = '192.168.1.1/files/path/to/xlsdocuments/'

 def index
 @xls_files = Dir.glob("*.xls")

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @articles }
 end
end
```

This would then allow me to loop through the @xls_files in my view.

Is this even remotely possible?

**UPDATE**

Using the above code in my controller as follows, I don't get any errors but I can't figure out how to display the file names:

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authorize, only: [:new, :edit, :update]
basedir = '192.168.1.1/common/'
  # GET /documents
  # GET /documents.json
  def index
    @documents = Document.all
    @xls_files = Dir.glob("*.xls")
    @xls_files = @xls_files.split('\n')

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @documents }
    end
  end
```

I'm looping through the file names using the following in my view:

```
<% @xls_files.each do |xls| %>
 file name
<% end %>
```

This outputs `file name`. Any idea how I output the actual filename?

Comment: Dir.glob returns an array, so I don't know why do you want to split that. Also correct me if I'm wrong, you can just mount this remote folder to local one, and then just use Dir.chdir with Dir.glob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else that may want to do this, these are the steps I took to get it working:

1. Mount the remote folder locally.

   `fusermount -u ~/yourmountdirectory`
2. List the contents of the local (remote) directory

   `@xls_files = Dir.glob("/home/danny/nurserotas/*")`

3.Output list in view of the files

```
<ul>
<% @xls_files.each do |xls| %>
<li><%= xls %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a command line like this :

```
@xls_files = `ssh 192.168.1.1 'ls /path/to/dir *.xls'`
@xls_files = @xls_files.split('\n')
```

Comment: If I'm connecting via SSH I would need to authenticate first. Adding -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've updated my question, I've got the file listings working but the base_dir (the IP) is being ignored. I just get the current servers directory contents instead of the remote ones.